# Recursive Drush make, working with different git branches

Tags: version-control, drush, aegir

## Setup

For every site we make a custom Drupal install profile is created, copies of which are built using `drush make` (through Aegir, though that should not make a difference).

There is a top-level build makefile for downloading Drupal core and our install profile, and the install profile contains a makefile specifying Features to download, each of which have a makefile specifying their dependencies (either custom modules in private git repos or contrib modules).

The build makefile (`build-SITENAME.make`) specifies the install profile like this:

```
projects[SITENAME_profile][type] = profile
projects[SITENAME_profile][download][type] = git
projects[SITENAME_profile][download][url] = git.hostname:drupal-sites/SITENAME_profile
```

Then the install profile's makefile will specify a bunch of Features to download, for example:

```
projects[blog][type] = module
projects[blog][subdir] = features
projects[blog][download][type] = git
projects[blog][download][url] = git.hostname:drupal-features/blog
```

Which will then download custom and contrib modules and so on.

The above setup has worked well for a couple of years.

## Problem

The problem occurs when trying to use git branches for managing different stages of development, e.g. development, staging and production; and having CI automatically manage Drupal sites for each branch. If a build is triggered for the development branch, `drush make` has to get the correct branch for every one of our repos it downloads.

Given our multi-repo and recursive makefile structure, how would `drush make` be used to recursively download the correct branch from our git repos?

## Things already tried

1. `drush make` allows downloading from a git branch, which seemed good
   for our use-case. For example, for each makefile (in the build,
   install profile and Features repositories) a line is added that
   looks like:

   ```
   projects[blog][download][branch] = development
   ```

   When the branch of the repo being downloaded matches the branch of the
   repo the makefile is in, custom modules specified in the
   development branch of the 'blog' Feature will be downloaded from
   that module's development branch. Great!

   However, this causes problems merging the branches of any repo containing a makefile (given our setup that's quite a lot), we will have to be extremely careful not to accidentally merge `[branch] = development` into master on any of them.
2. Checked `drush make` documentation for a command-line option to specify the default branch for git repository downloads. Found nothing.
3. Searched the Internet for people with similar quandaries, it seems many are dumping all the dependencies for whole projects into single make files, but that breaks the modularity of Features.

**Note**: I'm not polling or asking for discussion. I believe there's something silly I'm missing and/or something *everyone* else is doing that I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question! I maintain both Aegir and Drush Make, but I'm not certain that I have a really good answer for you.

1. I think that you're suggestion in (1) is probably the best bet at
   the moment. It has the virtue of already working, as you've
   mentioned. The issue with accidentally merging these `[branch]`
   attributes is still valid though. The solution though, lies not in
   Drush Make, but in Git!

   Check out this [article](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b). It describes using *Git attributes*,
   along with a custom (null) *Git merge driver*. To summarize, each
   developer would have to run the following:

   ```
   git config --global merge.ours.driver true
   ```

   This basically means that when an item is flagged to use the
   '*ours*' merge driver, it'll just call `/bin/true`, hence my earlier
   reference to it being a null operation.

   But, how do you flag your makefiles to use this driver? That's where
   *Git attributes* come into play. Create a `.gitattributes` file at the root of your repo (i.e., along side `.gitignore`). Then add the
   following line:

   ```
   build-SITENAME.make merge=ours
   ```

   You'll probably want to do the same for your feature repos as well.
2. As for solutions leveraging Drush Make, I don't know that there's a
   solid solution.

   A few years back, I experimented with using overrides trying to do
   something similar, as described in the [Drush Make
   documentation](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/#overriding-properties). The basic idea is that you can change (override)
   attributes from included makefiles.

   However, in the case of recursive makefiles, they are built
   separately, instead of being merged into the parent makefile prior
   to build. As a result, there's no opportunity to override their
   attributes. This may have changed in the time since I tested it, but
   I think the underlying mechanics remain largely the same, and so
   it's unlikely to work.

   Setting a [default](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/#defaults) in a parent makefile would be a nice way to
   accomplish something like this too. I haven't tested this, but
   again, I'm pretty sure the default wouldn't apply to the recursively
   built makefile.

   Instead, an option would be to build your parent makefile without
   recursion, but rather including the feature makefiles directly. You
   can now [include makefiles](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/#includes) directly from within a Git repo
   (using the new YAML syntax):

   ```
   includes:
     # A file from a git repository.
     makefile: "example_dir/example.make"
     download:
       type: "git"
       url: "git@github.com:organisation/repository.git"
       branch: "master"
   ```

   You'd either want to call `drush make` with the `--no-recursion`
   option, or specify it in your makefiles:

   ```
   --no-recursion                   Do not recurse into the makefiles of any
                                    downloaded projects; you can also set 
                                    [do_recursion] = 0 on a
                                    per-project basis in the makefile.
   ```

I'm sure there are other options available, but those are the ones that I think would least impact your existing workflows. I'd be very curious to see other suggestions.

There is a feature request to allow the [use of variables in .make files](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/456), which might address such a use-case more directly, if it were implemented. Perhaps we could look for such variables in options passed on the command line, or in environment variables.

That said, in the long run, I believe that Drush Make will be supplanted entirely by Composer, so it might be more fruitful to explore in that direction, if the suggestions above don't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which could be a bit more flexible regarding the recursive dependencies as it can analyze the whole dependency tree which you can set-up and many more.

See example [composer.json](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/composer.json):

```
...
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.20",
        "drupal/core": "8.0.*",
        "drush/drush": "8.*",
        "drupal/console": "~0.8",

        "drupal/devel": "8.1.*@dev",
        "drupal/token": "8.1.*@dev"
    },
...
```

See:

- [Composer vs. Drush Make: Which Should You Use?](https://pantheon.io/blog/composer-vs-drush-make-which-should-you-use)
- [Composer template for Drupal projects.](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)

Comment: There are several reasons I didn't pursue Composer: 1) I haven't heard of it providing anything particularly different to Drush make (for my particular use-case); 2) there's no Aegir integration; 3) it's very early days wrt its integration with Drupal; 4) I don't _think_ it works recursively, which would spoil the modularity of Features. I may be wrong, but Composer doesn't seem to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in managing different branches, please have a look how this is achieved in [ADS](https://www.drupal.org/project/ads) distribution ([GitHub](https://github.com/mycognitive/ads)).

Basically you can set-up CI to load the file appropriate for specific branch, e.g.:

```
build-SITENAME-BRANCH.make
```

then in this file you can have specific components of specific branch (e.g. profile) and everything else (e.g. common contrib modules) can be included from different `.make` files (`includes[] = contrib.make`). See: [build-ads-latest-dev.make](https://github.com/mycognitive/ads/blob/master/build-ads-latest-dev.make).

---

If this won't help, alternatively use editing in-place before running the build which will set the appropriate branches.

For example having this line where you specify your branch:

```
projects[foo][download][branch] = master
```

you can alter it via:

```
ex -s +"%s/master/develop/" -cwq build-SITENAME.make
```

Comment: We are using separate makefiles in the top-level build makefile, but the idea of doing this all the way through the dependency repos had not occurred to me, so that's definitely a valid answer to the problem (if a teeny bit messy!) I'd like to mod your answers up, but don't have the rep, sorry about that.